# How do I change my SOQL below so that Shield Platform Encryption is supported on SSN and the query supports large amounts of data

Tags: soql, sosl, encryption, platform-encryption, shield

Our company has several packages and we've recently been asked to do some analysis on how to make them compatible with Salesforce Shield field encryption.

In the [Shield encryption considerations doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_pe_considerations_general.htm&language=en_US), it states that encrypted fields can't be used in where clauses for SOQL and SOSL.

One of our packages uses a Contact field for Social Security Number that uniquely identifies a Contact within an org. How do you filter a SOQL/SOQL query when Social Security Number is encrypted? Especially if there are more than 50,000 Contact records in an org?

```
List<Contact> contacts = [select Id, Name from Contact where SocialSecurityNumber__c in :ssns];
```

Comment: Could you use a find sosl query to return the ids of the contacts, and then a normal soql query to get the fields you require? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm

Comment: Perhaps it's relevant here: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/61004/115819

Comment: @Kasper yes this could be an option - that is what they suggest [in the Code Examples implementing workarounds doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/ISVPlatformEncryption#Code_examples_implementing_these_workarounds). 

SOSL does have lower limits than SOQL though - [only allowed to issue 20 queries and return 2,000 records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm).

Comment: Oh sorry @SineadCoyle, i figured you only needed to return a limited number of those 50.000 plus records, but you need more. I don't think i'd know a foolproof solution except splitting up your jobs (batch apex or limit the user to a max of 40.000 records at a time.) Another way to go would be to create a one way hash of the social security number and use that for your queries. I'm not sure if your application would allow that though.

Comment: Thanks @Kasper yes we'll probably have to limit batch sizes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: see also [Deterministic Encryption](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/208189/2602) for resolving equality issues in SOQL WHERE

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ability to add a custom field where the last four of the SSN is masked I think there's a decent solution for you. If you can do that, you could query on the masked last four digits, then use a concatenation of the Contact Name and of the Last Four digits of the SSN to determine the correct account that you're looking for. That's the best scenario that comes to mind off the top of my head.