# Platform encryption - Rollup Helper managed package SOQL WHERE clause issue

Tags: platform-encryption

In my sandbox,  [Rollup helper managed package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI) has been used.

When try to encrypt Contact Name field by Platform encryption, System is unable to encrypt because in one of the classes is having SOQL query with **WHERE clause using Contact Name**.

> Encryption is now enabled on one or more fields. Encryption enablement has failed for the following fields:
>
> Contact.Name:
>
> Apex Class: PS_Resource_Manager_Behaviour, line 1831, column 28:

```
SELECT Count() FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Joe'
                              ^
```

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:35
>   field 'LastName' can not be filtered in a query call
>       Apex Class: PS_Resource_Manager_Behaviour, line 1832, column 31:
>   SELECT Count() FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE '%Test Record%'
>                                     ^
>   ERROR at Row:1:Column:35
>   field 'Name' can not be filtered in a query call

The API version of PS_Resource_Manager_Behaviour is 38.

What could be the workaround of this issue. We need to encrypt this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to use [Deterministic Encryption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_deterministic.htm) (beta as of Spring 42). You have to call SFDC Support for this to enable it (and you'll need to generate a new tenant secret)

You will not need to contact the package provider

With Deterministic Encryption

Works:

```
[select Id from Account where Name = 'Joe']
```

But this won't work:

```
[select Id from Account where Name LIKE 'Joe%']
```

To resolve the like operator issue, you have to use SOSL

Comment: If managed package already has `WHERE` clause with `LIKE` operator then who will change this?

Comment: @SantanuBoral OP was equality test so answer should work for OP. As for LIKE, the vendor must fix - I agree.  Vendor may say: "get lost" and then org is out-of-luck. Frankly, SFDC is leaving orgs with compliance requirements in the lurch for such common fields as Account.Name that participate in hundreds of appexchange packages. We have that issue with Apttus right now

Answer (score 3):

In my other sandbox the class's version is 41 where it is not giving that issue.

So, need to upgrade the package version.

**One recommendation to the package developer is NOT to use following Standard fields in SOQL WHERE clause** *otherwise*, **target environment will not able to encrypt fields by Shield Platform Encryption**.

> Account

- Account Name
- Account Mailing Address
- Physical Address (Only Shipping Street and Shipping City are encrypted.)
- Phone
- Fax
- Website
- Description
- Account Site

> Contact

- Name
- Other Address
- Mailing Address
- Phone
- Fax
- Mobile
- Home Phone
- Other Phone
- Asst. Phone
- Email
- Title
- Assistant
- Description

> Lead

- Name
- Title
- Company
- Address
- Phone
- Mobile
- Fax
- Email
- Website
- Description

> Opportunity

- Opportunity Name
- Description
- Next Step

> Case

- Subject
- Description

> Case Comment

- Body

> Contract

- Billing Address

Comment: no, I dont know the process, but this is valid issue

Comment: @sfdcfox different package to DLRS

Comment: @PhilHawthorn Oh, doh.

Comment: So, I was mistaken. Go to the application's listing, and click on the Support tab. They should have contact info there.

Comment: @SantanuBoral Thank you for sharing this. Can also provide official documentation link for this list?